# CSS Fixed position with Auto Margin

Tags: css

I want a component that keeps horizontal center of the page (two-columns), and I have a sub-component (right column) that I want its position to be fixed, so the sub-component's position to be fixed, but the whole two columns to be centered.

```
#content {
    width: 1200px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin-auto: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}

#right {
        width: 500px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: The correct answer should be pstenstrm's (most upvoted). It actually answers how you can use margin: auto, and it allows you to use something like width: 70%.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cant do that with `margin:auto`, but you can do something like this:

```
#CSS-SELECTOR-YOU-ARE-USING{
    background:#FF0000; // Just so you can see whats going on
    position:fixed; // Position the element
    right:50%; // Move it to the right for 50% of parent element
    margin-right:-250px; // You need here to put 1/2 of what you have below in width
    width:500px;
}
```

This way you move element to the right for 50%, and then move it back for half of its width. That way you get centered element with `position:fixed`.

Comment: Wait ! If you have other elements with `margin: auto` and `position: relative`, when you try to resize the width of browser, you will find out the two layers are not aligning correctly. This is a common bug of CSS.

Comment: This answer is correct if you have a fix width. For fluid width (i.e.100%) please consider pstenstrm's answer shown below

"You can use margin: 0 auto with position: fixed if you set left and right."

Comment: For new people coming to this thread: use the solution posted below

Comment: Isn't it the same thing and easier to set `right:25%` and avoid to use the margin-right ? It should do the same thing, given that 25% of 1000 is 250 ?

Am I wrong ?

Comment: This is a brilliant hack. Thank you!

Answer (score 90):

You can use `margin: 0 auto` with `position: fixed` if you set `left` and `right`.

```
.wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This also works with `position: absolute;` and vertically.

Demo: http://codepen.io/pstenstrm/pen/myaWVJ

Comment: Thank you good sir, your solution is better. I used to have `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` but it tend to blur the content of the page in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a wrapper as asolution for this problem:

```
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
.wrapper .right {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I found setting wrapper width 100% and top:0 fixed this for me. I was then able to set max-width and margin:auto on a child div and have it center.