# Aligning Two DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have a web page like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nuc9A/4/embedded/result/) ([codes](http://jsfiddle.net/nuc9A/4/)). AS you can see, there is a content div . And a little div which fixed to page, and scrolling with it. I want to align it to content div's left. I t will be like [this page](http://blog.tamindir.com/one-cikan-ozellikleriyle-yeni-iphone-4s/). There is a small fixed box which containing social sharing buttons. It's aligned to contents left. I want to do like this.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without javascript?

Comment: Is the markup order important? In other words: may the div's be rearranged or may the little div be placed inside the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuc9A/20/). I think it does what you want, but there are much nicer solutions when the order of the two div's can be rearranged.

Comment: he marked this as the solution, so it must be what is desired, but he was using fixed positioning so that the small div stayed as the page was scrolled.  Your solution appears to be using absolute positioning so scrolling down the page loses it...

Comment: @Lucas Yes, I know. Here on SO you have to able to grasp all of the unmentioned desires. OP didn't want a fixed position. He refers to an example in which the side box also scrolls. (Although not for long, I see now... ;)) I will try to find time to update the answer.

Comment: good point, i misunderstood the way it was stated and assumed since his initial example was fixed, thats what he wanted.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify your css for your sosyal-paylasim div to this (notice the last 2 elements):

```
#sosyal-paylasim {
    background-color: #F3F6FE;
    border-color: #A5B2D0 #DBE4F3 #DBE4F3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #E2E2E2;
    min-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    width: 64px;
    z-index: 100;

    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
}
```

Further explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232514/position-fixed-but-margin-auto/3232587#3232587).

----------- EDIT TO MAKE DIV OUTSIDE CONTAINER ---------------

Per your comment, if you want it outside of the container, use this:

```
#sosyal-paylasim {
    background-color: #F3F6FE;
    border-color: #A5B2D0 #DBE4F3 #DBE4F3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #E2E2E2;
    min-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    width: 64px;
    z-index: 100;

    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -557px;
}
```

The trick is that you are centering the div with the left: 50%, and then pushing it back to the left by half the width of the main container (plus the width of the div(64px) plus both borders for the div(2px) plus the left border for the container (1px) to make it outside).

Comment: Also, it's inside of content div. It must be outside.

Comment: @Eray I thought you wanted it inside, I will edit my answer for outside.