# Issue with making a picture centered in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make an image centered above login form..

here's the CSS code

```
.circular {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
  background: url("images/chris.jpg") no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

Still cannot achieve this.

Comment: This hard to answer without more context. Could you post the HTML which uses this class, preferably in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232514/css-fixed-position-with-auto-margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your element has a fixed width, you can simply use css calc for it.

```
.circular {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 75px);
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url("images/chris.jpg") no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

Comment: alright thank you... problem fixed but another question? how about moving it a little bit down because its sticking to the page?

Comment: Well, to do that you can simply change the `top` attribute to something bigger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, and like the comment from @ohAuth said, a little bit more context would be nice. But you want the center of the image, to be at the center of the cirkel?

You could do that by:

replacing this:

```
.circular {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: auto;
bottom: auto;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 150px;
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
background: url("images/chris.jpg") no-repeat;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

With this:

```
.circular {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: auto;
bottom: auto;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 150px;
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
background: url("images/chris.jpg") no-repeat center center;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

> More specific:

This:

```
background: url("images/chris.jpg") no-repeat;
```

With this:

```
background: url("images/chris.jpg") no-repeat center center;
```

That should put the image in the center.

Let me know if it works :)