# Problem to center div on bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have 2 container: I want to put the first on top and center it (no problem to do this with `margin:0 auto;`).

**However, I'm not able to put the second in the bottom center.**

I'm trying to align a div to the center in bottom position (like a footer div but not at width 100%).
My div has a width of 90% and it is impossible to center it. It is always aligned to the left.
If I use `margin: 0 auto;` it goes to the center but not at the bottom of the page. If I use `position: absolute; bottom:0;` it goes in bottom of the page but not aligned to the center.

Does anyone have an explanation?

PS: I would like to keep the HTML unchanged and not create another div to contain the second div.

```css
.a {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.b {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```

Comment: just add left:0; right:0; to the css on .b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what other HTML you have in place besides the two divs. Will you have a div in-between "a" and "b"? Will there be a wrapper div around all the divs? You could use CSS grid for your solution.

Here's the CSS:

```
    /* ideally this would be on a wrapper div instead of the body tag */
    body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 90px; /*This is the row heights*/
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    }

    .a {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    background-color: beige;
    }

    .b {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    }
```

Then your markup would stay the same:

```
    <div class="a">A</div>   
    <div class="b">B</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So with `position: fixed` you've effectively detached that element from the DOM flow so `margin: 0 auto` is now irrelevant, instead you'll want to do one of several other options to accomplish your goal. A couple examples (Note: the snippet editor won't do `position: fixed` well either so you'll want to try it locally);

```css
.a {
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.b {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    height: 10%;    
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>   
<div class="b">B</div>
```

OR,

```css
.a {
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.b-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
}

.b {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>

<div class="b-container">
  <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have high enough reputation to comment on answers, but you can use

```
left: 0; right: 0;
```

on your .b div without having to put a container around it.  I've tried it out and is working under Google Chrome.

There's some more explanation here - [CSS Fixed position with Auto Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232514/css-fixed-position-with-auto-margin)

Answer (score 0):

Give `.b` the following:

```
left: 5%;
```

`margin: auto` won't work on absolutely-positioned elements, only static ones.

Comment: Well, from what you posted, this will work. You gave `.b` position fixed; therefore, giving it width 90% and left 5% will centre it. That's maths for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a header and a footer? And the footer always on bottom?
Use a more modern flex layout to do this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-header-main-footer?embed=1&file=style.css

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, main, footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Q: How does it work? 
A: The main is a flex spacer.

PS: header, main and footer is just a suggestion. You also can use just divs.

Answer (score 0):

@chris..... solution A not work and B I want to keep unchange html @utkanos.....left: 5% is good but i don't want to calculate the space beetween (image if the width was 775 px) @Dominik.... div are not fully width and the 2 container could be different width